# Sometimes System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005)

Tags: windows, dcom

I am calling a Function of a Service from a homepage.
The strange thing is, this works for hours, then I do not change anything and suddenly I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
```

Then it doesn't work anymore. 
When I restart the server, it works again. I am pretty sure that this is a setting in the dcom config of the Service, but I already tried everything.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this isn't a setting in the dcom config of the Service, iff you already tried everything.

Comment: That is CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE, "Server execution failed".  Notoriously debugged from the wrong end, all you can see at the client end is a "it didn't work" error code.  You have to debug it on the server end.  A security problem is not very likely, it rarely behaves randomly.  The process just plain falling over and terminating when it starts up is the root cause. Having hundreds of server processes running would be an explanation for example.